# Insert query for ms-access with Oledb object getting exception of not a valid query

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net, oledb

I'm using the following code and it is giving the invalid Insert command exception.

row the DataRow object to be added to the database , conn is the OleDBConnection object.

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = `"Insert Into Appointments(ID,Body,End,Location,Start,Subject,Properties)"
                                                + "Values(@ID,@Body,@End,@Location,@Start,@Subject,@Properties)";


cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.WChar).Value = row[0].ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Body", OleDbType.WChar).Value = row[1].ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@End", OleDbType.Date).Value =  Convert.ToDateTime(row[2]).Date.ToLongDateString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Location", OleDbType.WChar).Value = row[3].ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Start", OleDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(row[4]).Date.ToLongDateString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Subject", OleDbType.WChar).Value = row[5].ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Properties", OleDbType.WChar).Value = row[6].ToString();


                conn.Open();                    
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();          //At this line exception is generating
                conn.Close();
```

Please help me in this.

Comment: Post the complete error message

Comment: {"Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got one (possibly more) [reserved word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_words) in your table's field names.

The field name **End** ... at the very least.

Try

```
cmd.CommandText = `"Insert Into Appointments(ID,Body,[End],Location,Start,Subject,Properties)"
                                                + "Values(@ID,@Body,@End,@Location,@Start,@Subject,@Properties)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Does "Appointments" table support inserting ID? If ID column is the identity value, that may cause problem.

Comment: ID is a primary key & it is of type Text but it might not create problem as it is from a dataset with same schema as database.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the data-types that you use for your parameters are incorrect.

If your ID column is a numeric column, you shouldn't use `OleDbType.WChar`, but `OleDbType.Integer`, for instance

For alfanumeric-columns, I wouldn't use `OleDbType.WChar` either, but `OleDbtype.VarChar`.

See the [OleDbType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype.aspx) enumeration as well.